# How to schedule a spark-submit scala jar in cloudera workbench enterprise edition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera, workbench

How can a jar file be scheduled in Cloudera Workbench? Currently, only options to schedule Python and Scala files seem to be available.